# Change github account credentials

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I was trying to push another github account repo up using the same computer's Android Studio. Somehow when I pushed it, it asked for credentials of the new account.

But right now I am trying to work on my previous github repo but do not have access to it as I believe I am still logged on the previous account? How do I get the screen that pops up asking for my github credentials when pushing?

I have tried going to `File -> Settings-> Version Control-> Github` and changed the account but it seems like I am just logged in on the wrong account.

*PS: While using command-line function of git does solve the issue. That defeats the purpose of integration. Integration of github with android studio is very neat and easy way to handle repo and I would love to solve this issue.*

Please see attached for the pop-up login I was referring to. How do I get this back?

[image]

Comment: Try using the terminal if you have Git installed, then you can remove Android Studio / any IDE from the problem

Comment: @cricket_007 I have not used command-line function of git before. Would be glad if you could guide me along

Comment: There's lots of resources out there. StackOverflow isn't a tutorial service, sorry.

Comment: While using command-line function of git does solve the issue. But integration of github with android studio is very neat and easy way and I would love to solve this issue.